# C++ struct with anonymous union

Tags: c++, variant, standard-layout, trivially-copyable, anonymous-union

---- updated -------------------------------------------

At first, I think that the problem I faced is `trivially_copyable`. In fact, even I give up making it `trivially_copyable`, it still can **NOT** be compiled.

Now, I'm only trying to get it pass compilation.

---- original question ---------------------------------

I have a struct that will be sent/received between processes through some type of message queue, so I want to make it fixed length, and `standard_layout` and `trivially_copyable`.

There are multiple types of my message(e.g. timer-msg, control-msg, order-msg and so on), then I'm trying to use a `union` to carry different types of messages.

The reason I don't want to use `std::variant`, is that I want to exactly control the length and the layout of my message struct.

Furthermore, I don't want to code too long when I refer its members. For example:
`msg.as_time` is little more readable than `msg.union_body.as_time`.
So I plan to use an anonymous union to carry the message body.

I'm expecting this(but it was rejected by gcc):

```
#include <chrono>

using TimeStamp_t = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;

enum MsgType_e { Timer, Count, };

struct Message_t {
    union {
        TimeStamp_t as_time;
        int64_t     as_int;
    };

    MsgType_e  type;
};

static_assert( std::is_standard_layout_v<Message_t> );
static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Message_t> );

int main() {
    Message_t msg;
    std::cout << msg.as_time.time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

Eventhough `MsgType_e` and `TimeStamp_t` are both `trivially_copyable`, `Message_t` is **NOT**, as long as I put `TimeStamp_t` into a anonymous union.

> error: use of deleted function 'Message_t::Message_t()'
>
> note: 'Message_t::Message_t()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>
> union member 'Message_t::::as_time' with non-trivial 'constexpr std::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Dur>::time_point() [with _Clock = std::chrono::_V2::system_clock; _Dur = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> >]'

How to make this struct `trivially_copyable`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have bad news for you: You *can't* "control the length and the layout" of the structure, since you're using a type that you have no control over. What is the underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need this "control" of the structure? How is that "control" going to solve the original problem? Are you going to send it in raw binary form over a network connection, or save to a file?

Comment: You can't make something trivially copyable.  For it to be trivial means it needs so simple the compiler default works just fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need to make it as a POD.

Comment: `struct Message_t { MsgType_e type; std::byte buffer[1024]; TimeStamp_t as_time() { TimeStamp_t result; memcpy(&result, buffer, sizeof result); return result; } int64_t as_int() { int result; memcpy(&result, buffer, sizeof result); return result;} };` (I picked 1024 out of thin air, you can use whatever is the size you want that suffices for your purposes.)

Comment: @Eljay I think in this case std::bit_cast is preferable over memcpy

Comment: But *why* do you need it to be a POD? What is the underlying and actual problem you need to solve? What is your assignment? What are you supposed to do with the structure?

Comment: If it's for network transfer or file saving, then *don't!* Use an existing serialization framework to convert the structure into something that can be transferred or saved in a portable format, without having to worry about things like it being a POD, endianness issues, or any other of the multitude of problems that you (or others) could encounter.

Comment: @Eljay With your method, everytime I access its members, some extra instructions will be executed.

Comment: @Leon • that is true.  If you profile it (on an optimized build), I expect it will have no overhead compared to a `union`.

Comment: _so I want to make it fixed length, and standard_layout and trivially_copyable_ I disagree with this conclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make this struct `trivially_copyable`?

I would just follow the directions in the error message:

> error: use of deleted function 'Message_t::Message_t()'

Just add one:

```
Message_t() : as_time{}, type{} {}
```

[Works here.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YBA6AhGzYBKAP7kp)